# Does mosh save bandwidth?

Tags: ssh, bandwidth, mosh

[The mobile shell](https://mosh.mit.edu/) claims many benefits, especially with mobile connections. Many mobile plan prices scale with the amount of data transferred. So I wonder whether I can use Mosh to cut down in data usage. [A tutorial on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-mosh-on-a-vps) states that

> Mosh [...] will only communicate changes to the currently visible screen area. This allows it to radically reduce the bandwidth [...]

But does not give any statistics on how much bandwidth is gained and whether this really weighs out the additional overhead of establishing and maintaining a connection via UDP.

Are there any tests, experiences that compare SSH to Mosh in real-world-scenarios, especially

- used with *screen* or *tmux*,
- on a mobile connection while moving between different connection modes or cell towers,
- for long-lived sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mosh will probably *increase* your data usage. It is designed to increase *reliability* and *responsiveness*, or at least the illusion of it.

From [this discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/mosh-devel@mit.edu/msg00281.html), we know that mosh's predictive capabilities actually causes an extra packet being sent per keystroke. If you are concerned about metered data usage, you might want to use the `lowbandwidth` [branch of mosh](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/commit/979c2a1cb7e61998f2b6ffec0b019167bd2be616).